# Pass ID variable to Datatable jquery init function

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have problem passing ID variable to Datatable init functions.
What I want is :

Pressing link

```
<a href="#" data-id="' + data.id + '" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ipvpn_show_members">Show</a>
```

Modal window is opening and there I have datatable. And I want to pass `data-id` data to `ajax.data`. I tried to do like that:

```
        "data": function ( d ){
             d.id = $(this).data('id');
    }
```

with no luck .

Here is Jquery code for init datatable

```
    var member_table = $('#member_table').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "bFilter": false,
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bSort" : false,
    "bInfo" : false,
    "ajax": {
        "url": "/get_member_data",
        "dataType": "json",
        "dataSrc": "data",
        "contentType": "application/json",
        "data": function ( d ){
            d.id = $(this).data('id');

        }
    },
    "columns": [
        {"data": "vrf_name"},
        {"data": "primary_rt"},
        {"data": "ipvpn_rt"},
    ]

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by reloading ajax after id var initialisation

```
        $('#ipvpn_show_members').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
        var data = $(e.relatedTarget).data();
        member_table.ajax.url("\get_member_data?id="+data.id).load();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

add a class in link to make a dynamic function

```
   <a href="#" data-id="' + data.id + '" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ipvpn_show_members" class="my_modal">Show</a>
```

add an event to on modal show,

```
$(document).on('show.bs.modal', '.my_modal', function (e) {
    let id =  $(this).data('id');
    // here is your datatable code and use id in ajax
});
```

PS: if in case model dont show up, you can manually trigger it using $('#ipvpn_show_members').modal('show')